# android material design Searchbar scrolling Animation

Tags: android, scroll, material-design, smooth-scrolling, searchbar

I could not find any documentation, example or sample about searchbar with material design animation [like this](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HNUFCLXIwV2FOcDQ/components_bottomnavigation_behavior_backtotop.webm). Could anyone lead me how could I implement it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need a **Collapsing Toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
```

Full code example code could be found [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_AppBar_and_Collapsing_Toolbar_Layouts)

and a **Bottom Navigation View**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Full code example could be found [here](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0)

Answer (score 0):

Putting it all together and using the scroll-away mode, the SearchBar and SearchView widgets can be used in your layout as such:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- NestedScrollingChild goes here (NestedScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint" />
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:hint="@string/searchbar_hint"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
    <!-- Search suggestions/results go here (ScrollView, RecyclerView, etc.). -->
  </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md